# Number of unique ways to select $3$ balls from $4$ red balls, $2$ green balls and $1$ blue ball

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there is a jar with $7$ balls: $4$ red, $2$ green and $1$ blue.
In how many unique ways can we choose $3$ balls?

Just by considering all the possibilities, I found out the answer is $6$. Namely:

- red, red, red
- red, red, green
- red, red, blue
- green, green, red
- green, green, blue
- blue, green, red

I was wondering if it is possible to express the solution in terms of the amount of different colors (in this case $3$) and the quantity per color. (in this case $4$, $2$ and $1$)

Comment: It is possible.  That said, for the given numbers, simply listing the possibilities is probably the most efficient method.

Comment: Another way to look at it is : Let $x_1,x_2,x_3$ be the number of red, green and blue balls respectively. You wish to find all possible solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3=3$ such that $0\leq x_1\leq 4, 0\leq x_2\leq 2, 0\leq x_3\leq 1$. By the way your answer is $^7C_3$ I guess.

Comment: One might also think of this as a sample problem for counting the number of contingency tables with two rows and three columns having prescribed marginal sums.  Even for two rows but arbitrarily many columns such counting problems [have been shown to be NP hard](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/MCC17/Papers/contingency.pdf).

Comment: @YadatiKiran $\binom{7}{3}$ is an answer to a related but *different* question where the balls were all distinctly labeled.  Here, presumably, the red balls are all identical, etc...  Your rephrasing of the question however is correct, but the method of solution would likely either involve brute force, or inclusion-exclusion with stars and bars which is likely just as tedious as brute force here.

Comment: An alternate solution, which if you have access to computer software is easy to implement for reasonable numbers (*but is practically brute force in disguise*) is to look at the coefficient of $x^3$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2)(1+x)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Just a forethought Isnt this question like "Choosing 3 balls from 7 balls"? Because it does not matter which colour the ball is.

Comment: Number of **unique** ways.  Here, one way of selecting is considered to be unique from another iff the number of at least one color chosen is different.  For example pulling two red balls and a blue ball is considered to be "different" than pulling all three balls as red.  On the other if the balls did happen to have numbers on them as well, pulling (Red1, Red2, Green1) is considered to be "the same" outcome as pulling (Green2, Red1, Red 4) since in both cases we pulled two red balls and one green ball.  This should have been clear from context and his list of outcomes above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the polynomial
$$\eqalign{p(x)&:=(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2)(1+x)\cr  &=(1-x^5)(1-x^3)(1-x^2)(1-x)^{-3}\cr  &=(1-x^5)(1-x^3)(1-x^2)\sum_{k\geq0}{2+k\choose k}x^k\ .\cr}\tag{1}$$
For each admissible choice of $r\in[0 .. 4]$ red balls, $g\in[0 .. 2]$ green balls, and $b\in[0 .. 1]$ blue balls the expansion of this polynomial creates a term $x^r\,x^g\,x^b=x^{r+g+b}$. Now we want $r+g+b=3$. It follows that we have to extract  $N:={\rm coeff}[x^3]$ on the last line of $(1)$. Since
$$(1-x^5)(1-x^3)(1-x^2)=1-x^2-x^3+{\rm higher\ terms}$$
it follows that 
$$N={2+3\choose3}-{2+1\choose1}-{2+0\choose0}=6\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

We can also solve this problem using the inclusion-exclusion principle. Let $r$, $g$, $b$ represent the number of red, green and blue balls respectively. We want to find all solutions of the equation

$r+g+b=3$

Subject to

$\begin{equation}
0 \leq r \leq 4 \\ 
0 \leq g \leq 2 \\
0 \leq b \leq 1
\end{equation}$

Let $A$ be the set of all solutions of $r+g+b=3$, under only the lower bound constraints, that is, $r, g, b \geq 0$. We can find the number of solutions of $A$ by treating it as a typical "unordered selection with repetition"-problem. (This is analogous to the number of ways to divide 3 items into 3 boxes). $|A| = {3+3-1\choose 3-1} = 10$

Let $R$, $G$, $B$ be the set of solutions that violate the upper bound constraints of the red, green and blue balls respectively.

$R$ has the additional constraint that $r \geq 5$. Then, $r+g+b\geq 5 > 3$, so $|R|=0$

$G$ has the additional constraint that $g \geq 3$. This means $g=3$ and $r=b=0$, so $|G|=1$

$B$ has the additional constraint that $b \geq 2$. Let $b'=b-2$, then the problem becomes $r+g+b' = 1$ s.t. $r, g, b' \geq 0$. This problem has ${1+3-1\choose 3-1} = 3$ solutions.

To apply the inclusion exclusion principle, we also need to solve for all combinations of $R, G, B$. By similar reasoning, we can show that $|R \cap G| = |G \cap B| = |R \cap B| = |R \cap G \cap B| = 0$.

Now we find the solution of the problem with the original constraints by subtracting the solutions that violated the upper bounds from $A$ and applying the inclusion-exclusion principle:

$\begin{align}
|A| - |R \cup G \cup B| &= |A| - |R| - |G| - |B| + |R \cap G| + |G \cap B| + |R \cap B| - |R \cap G \cap B| \\
&= 10 - 0 - 1 - 3 + 0 + 0 + 0 - 0 \\
&= 6
\end{align}$